# While using screen reader such as NVDA, how to press Left or Right key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screen-readers

While using screen reader such as NVDA, when left or right key is pressed, the screen reader reads the current or next element letter by letter.

If anybody knows how can I press left or right key to trigger the element's keypress event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A screen reader has two modes: **browse mode** (where keyboard events are sent to the screen reader) and **forms mode** (where keyboard events are sent to the html element).

The default setting for most screen readers is to have automatic switching between the two modes for certain types of html elements, although you can manually switch between the two modes as well.

So the key to having keyboard events sent to your element is to use the [right html element](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_generalnav) (these are elements that require keyboard focus management) or use the [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) for that element.

The following elements will automatically switch between browse mode (arrow key reading the next character) and forms mode (the html element handling the arrow key):

- Combobox
- Grid
- Listbox
- Menu or menu bar
- Radiogroup
- Tabs
- Toolbar
- Tree Grid
- Tree View

Some of these elements have a native html element (eg, `<input type='radio'>`) but others require the role (eg, `<div role='tablist'>`).

If your component doesn't fall into one of these widgets, then you can use [`role="application"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#application) but I always caution about using that role.  It's often misused and can make a website difficult to use for a screen reader user if the role isn't used correctly.

Comment: Thanks slugolicious. It works after I switch to forms mode by pressing [NVDA] + <SPACE>.

Comment: Yes, you can manually switch but you have to ask yourself if the user should have to do that or if it should automatically switch for them.

Comment: In my case, the control is a draggable button that serves as a column resize handler in a data grid. For keyboard operability, it uses keypress events of <left> and <right> key to emulate the click-and-drag behavior. NVDA probably doesn't automatically switch to `Forms Mode` on a button. And since it's inside a third party component, I can't test it with `application` role. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know if I have some new findings.

Comment: Yes, we implemented column resizing for tables too, using the drag column width paradigm.  We used a modified arrow (like ctrl+left or shift+left) to do the resizing.